# Print ABC - string

Tags: c, arrays, string

1. My program need to print all the ABC but I see I have problems with the code. How I can fix it? **(no pointer for this time).**
2. What is the runtime error in the code and how to fix it?

Here is the code:

```
// Elvis’s hip and happening ABC-printing code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 26
void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main() {
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET] = "";
    makeABC(abcString);
    puts(abcString);
    return (0);
}

void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]) {
    char letter;
    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        strcat(abc, letter);
    }
}
```

Comment: `char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET]` will not be large enough to allow for the `nul` terminator. You are *trying to* concatenate 26 "letters" so the target string size must be 27 at least.

Comment: What do you mean, "what is the runtime error"? Why don't you know what it is?

Comment: "no pointer for this time" - Wrong assumption. You can hardly do anything in C with an array without using a pointer. And it is your's to tell what error you get and where! Learn [ask].

Comment: Compiler warnings are not just to show some fancy messages during compilation! Enable and pay heed to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try something like following? I haven't tested the following but it should work on most part.

```
// Elvis’s hip and happening ABC-printing code

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET 26
void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET]);

int main()
{
  char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET + 1];
  makeABC(abcString);
  puts(abcString);
  return 0;
}

void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET + 1])
{
   char letter;
   int i=0;
   for(letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++)
   {
     abc[i] = letter;
     i++;
   }
   abc[i]='\0';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the [`strcat`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcat) function expects *both* arguments to be (zero-terminated) strings. You only pass one string, and then one *single character* as arguments (which should give you compiler warnings).

You need to convert this single characters into a string (or an *array*) of a single character.

And don't forget that strings in C are zero-terminated.

---

What happens you use the single character as argument to the `strcat` function is that the compiler converts it to an `int` which is then in turn converted to a pointer. The problem with this is that the address `'a'` (for example) is not a valid address to a string. That will lead to *undefined behavior* and a crash.

Answer (score 1):

Your program logic is correct, the problem is the calling of the `strcat()` function. The `strcat()` function is implemented as:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
 char *ret = dest;
 while (*dest)
    dest++;
 while (*dest++ = *src++);
 return ret;
}
```

The second argument must be a string instead which you pass a character.
This is the reason for your run time error.

Answer (score 0):

Your program has several issues:

- You cannot call `strcat` with a `char`, you must pass `char *` arguments, pointing to null terminated C strings.
- The array into which you compose the alphabet is too short: you need to define it with a size one larger than the number of characters for the final `'\0'` terminator.

Here is a corrected version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUM_ABC_LET  ('z' - 'a' + 1)  // 26 ASCII letters

void makeABC(char *abc);  // makeABC receives a pointer to an array of char
                          // this declaration is equivalent to
                          // void makeABC(char abc[NUM_ABC_LET+1]);
                          // but less error prone

int main(void) {
    char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET + 1] = "";
    makeABC(abcString);
    puts(abcString);
    return 0;
}

void makeABC(char *abc) {
    char letter;
    char buf[2];  // a buffer for a 1 letter C string

    for (letter = 'a'; letter <= 'z'; letter++) {
        buf[0] = letter;  // make a 1 letter string
        buf[1] = '\0';    // set the null terminator
        strcat(abc, buf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prototype of strcat is
char *strcat(char *destination, const char *source);

means our source as well as destinations should and must be string so this is the issue that why if you compile in turbo c it will through error of

"type mismatch".

and if you wanna write program for printing ABC up to Z than simply write

void main()
{

```
  int i;
  for(i = 65; i<=90; i++)
  {
      printf("%c", i);
  }
```

}

I hope you will like it......

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation, I would suggest passing the length of the character array to the function, so that the function does not overflow the array.

As the character array is passed to the function as a pointer, the function does not know it's size.

In your case you know the size, but for the future it might be better to explicitly pass the size.

Also I just copied the characters rather than use strcat, and added the null termination at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_ABC_LET 26

/* function takes pointer to array and size of array */
void makeABC(char *abc, int len);

int main()
{
  /* array needs to include space for null termination */
  char abcString[NUM_ABC_LET + 1];
  /* call function with pointer + size */
  makeABC(abcString, NUM_ABC_LET);
  printf("%s\n", abcString);
  return (0);
}

void makeABC(char *abc, int len)
{
    int n;
    for(n = 0; n < len; n++ ) {
        /* add letters to the array */
        abc[n] = n + 'a';
    }
    /* put a null termination on the end */
    abc[n] = '\0';
}
```